# Dropdown Content open on submenu

Tags: submenu

I am working on a dropdown menu from bootstrap I have surrounded by bootstrap tags and a dropdown content class.  I have the dropdown menu functioning, but only want the submenu/content dropdown area to show if you hover on a menu that has a submenu.  The example i have is on https://www.homedepot.com/ .  If you hover over the "All Departments" tab, only one column shows for the parent menu categories, then the further down it opens more depending on which menu you hover over.  Can this be done?

Comment: Let me guess - Access Denied!...You don't have permission to access "http://www.homedepot.com/" on this server - probably not ;)

Comment: Yeah, I mean, at best, I can see some of the styles, but other components are minified and I don't see any main javascript functions in place.  Was not looking for anything but some breadcrumbs, but the functionality isn't there besides the tags for flyout menu